# How can I parse data from inside a tag with Applescript?

Tags: macos, mac, html, applescript, parsing

How can I parse data from inside a tag with Applescript? I know Applescript has the `words 3 thru -2 of myTextVariable` syntax - but how would I use it to be sure I am just getting 
`This is my text` from the tags below?

```
<p>This is my text</p>
```

or

```
<p class="new">This is my text</p>
```

or

```
<h1>This is my text</h1>
```

or

```
<content class="new" id="content">This is my text</content>
```

Comment: In a hurry, but see: [Parsing HTML in AppleScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236907/parsing-html-in-applescript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just use regex in the shell or in some shell scripting language:

`paragraphs of (do shell script "/bin/echo " & quoted form of "<p class=\"new\">yyy</p><p>uuu</p>" & " | ruby -e 'puts $<.read.scan(/<p.*?>(.+?)<\\/p>/)'")`

Comment: Thanks @Lri I was hoping from an answer from the AppleScript expert :) I had been doing something similar but was just wondering if there was a better way - glad you are in support of using the shell. One thing though, why use `/bin/echo` instead of `echo` but not `/usr/bin/ruby` instead of `ruby` ?

Comment: @cwd Because the default echo in `sh` eats backslashes: [osx - How can I escape shell arguments in AppleScript? - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138167/how-can-i-escape-shell-arguments-in-applescript/8145515#8145515)